# Jenkins / Sonar integration

Tags: java, jenkins, driver, sonarqube, h2

I am trying to use the jenkins sonar plugin,

whenever i try to do a build i get the following error;

```
> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution ERROR: Unable to execute
> Sonar ERROR: Caused by: Fail to connect to database ERROR: Caused by:
> Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.h2.Driver' for connect URL
> 'http://localhost:9092/sonar' ERROR: Caused by: No suitable driver
> ERROR:  ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Sonar
> Runner with the -e switch. ERROR: Re-run Sonar Runner using the -X
> switch to enable full debug logging. Build step 'Invoke Standalone
> Sonar Analysis' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE
```

My properties file for sonar server has the following entries

```
#----- Credentials
# Permissions to create tables and indexes must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username=                       sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=                       sonar

#----- Embedded database H2
# Note : it does not accept connections from remote hosts, so the
# sonar server and the maven plugin must be executed on the same host.

# Comment the following line to deactivate the default embedded database.
sonar.jdbc.url=                           jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar;create=true
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:               org.h2.Driver

# directory containing H2 database files. By default it's the /data directory in the sonar installation.
sonar.embeddedDatabase.dataDir=D:/Sonar/sonar-3.2/data
# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
sonar.embeddedDatabase.port:               9092
```

My config file in jenkins for sonar contains the following;

```
>  # Additional parameters sonar.jdbc.dialect=h2
> sonar.jdbc.driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
> sonar.jdbc.driver=D:\Sonar\sonar-3.2\extensions\jdbc-driver\h2\h2-1.3.167.jar
```

What setting am i missing here for the driver to be found?

Thanks

Comment: MAybe the colon after driverClassName should be an = ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Maven logs and your pom.xml : I suspect your are using an old version of the maven Sonar plugin.

Maybe your are forcing its version to 2.0.

The plugin should be either

> org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5

or

> org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.5

Comment: im not using maven at all?

Comment: have you followed these instructions ? http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Sonar+Runner Do not forget to set the SONAR_RUNNER_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Is your Sonar runner running without jenkins? I mean that can you access your sonar's URL?